# Google Authentication with WebApi - BadRequest

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**Code in Node.Js**

```
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

var params = {
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
    code: req.body.code,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_secret: config.GOOGLE_SECRET
};

console.log(req.body.code);

request.post(url, {
    json: true,
    form: params
}, function (err, response, token) {
    var accessToken = token.access_token;
)};
```

**Code in Web Api**

```
    var clientd = new ClientD()
        {
            client_id = client_id,
            redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
            client_secret = client_secret,
            code = code,
            grant_type = grant_type
        };


    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
            using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add
                (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientd);
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            }
```

I have a code for google authentication in node.js which is working fine. When I try to re-write the code in a controller of wep-api I get a bad request error. 
Where am I going wrong ? Any help  ?
**Note**: The client-id's and other info are perfectly set in both the cases.